# gmail reply to not working with javamail: cannot set reply

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-pop

I can send mails with gmail with javamail

But i cannot set the reply to anyhow...

the code i m using is...

```
   //the actual mail id someone@gmail.com
   ccAddress = new InternetAddress( "someone+something@gmail.com");

        msg.setFrom(ccAddress);

        Address[] addresses = new Address[1];
        //actually i want to addressee to reply-to
        addresses[0] = new InternetAddress( "someone@yahoo.com" );
        msg.setReplyTo(addresses);

        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(text);
        msg.setHeader("MIME-Version" , "1.0" );
        msg.setHeader("Content-Type" , "text/html" );
        msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", "Recommend-It Mailer V2.03c02");
```

Comment: Are you using Transport.send() or Transport.sendMessage()?

Comment: transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `transport.sendMessage()`, try calling `msg.saveChanges()`
The send() function calls this before calling sendMessage(), but if you are using sendMessage() yourself, you will have to call this to make sure any headers are saved.

Comment: You're already calling saveChanges() ?  Interesting.  Is the X-Mailer header getting saved?

Comment: ya X-mailer is saved and shown on the headers when i check the sent mail in gmail...

Comment: is your 'from' address the same address you are logging into gmail with?

Comment: so sorry for troubling you out here... was a problem with re-deploying a ejb...a big thanks for your time...